# track parent enitites using hibernate listener

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to track my parent enitites by using hibernate event listeners (PostUpdateEventListener, PostInsertEventListener, etc).  When an update happens on a parent entity where the change is made to an associated entity, hibernate returns the associated entity instead of the parent.  Is there a way to find/know the parent entity when changes are made to associated entities?  thanks

Comment: You can try `object.getClass().getSuperclass()`

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add relationship from child to parent to traverse back.

```
<many-to-one name="parent" inverse="true">
</many-to-one>
```